# number of divisors (prime numbers)

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

i need to find the number of divisors to at-least divide one of the following numbers

$10^{40}$$,$ $20^{30}$ $,$ $40^{20}$ after factorising we get that   $10^{40}$=$2^{40}$$*$ $5^{40}$ $,$ $20^{30}$=$2^{60}$$*$ $5^{30}$ and $40^{20}$ $=$ $2^{60}$$*$ $5^{20}$
i tried using the inclusion exclusion principle ( i used $|U- $A$_{1} $∪$ $A$_{2}$∪$ $A$_{3}|$ =S$_{0}$-S$_{1}$+S$_{2}$-S$_{3}$ )
so we get that S$_{0}$ = $41*41+61*31+61*21=4853$ which is all the options , but i get the same thing for S$_{1}$.
for S$_{2}$ = A$_{1}$ $∩$ A$_{2}$$...$ i take the smallest out of the powers so i get

$41*31+41*21+61*21=3413$ , when i get to S$_{3}$ = A$_{1}$ $∩$ A$_{2}$ $∩$ A$_{3}$ i take the smallest out of them all $41*21=861$ 
my final answer is $4853-4853+3413-861=2552$ which is **wrong** , the answer should be **2301** but i cannot get to it

what am i doing wrong? am i using the inclusion exclusion principle wrong as well?

Edit: i noticed that if i do it without the S$_{1}$ i get the right answer but why? $4853-3413+861=2301$

thanks to any helpers

Comment: Note:   $30^{20}=2^{20}\times 3^{20}\times 5^{20}$.

Comment: $2301=41\times41+20\times31$

Comment: I don't understand the proposed solution(s).  There are $21^3=9261$ divisors of $30^{20}$ alone so the proposed answers seem much too small.

Comment: did you mean $61\color{red}\times31+61\color{red}\times21$ and $\color{red}40^{20}=2^{60}5^{20}$?

Comment: Or maybe you meant $40^{20}$ instead of $30^{20}$? But it's hard to guess what you meant.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: im sorry i just noticed that i typed 30 instead of 40 , thank you i edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you indicated, there are $41\times41$ factors of $10^{40}=2^{40}5^{40}$.

There are $20\times31$ factors of $20^{30}=2^{60}5^{30}$ that are not factors of $10^{40}=2^{40}5^{40}$;

they are of the form $2^n5^m$, where $41\le n\le 60$ and $0\le m\le 30$.

All factors of $40^{20} $ are factors of $20^{30}$.

Thus, there are $41\times41+20\times31$ factors of the three numbers.

Comment: thank you for the help , but why didn't my way with the inclusion exclusion principle work ? can you please tell me where  i did wrong?

Comment: the principle should be $ |A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|=|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|-(|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_3|+|A_2\cap A_3|)+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|$